# Growler fillups in San Jose/South Bay Area

Tags: growlers

So I just recently got a growler and so far so great. The only problem I am having is finding places where I can fill up. Does anyone have any recommendations as to location in the San Francisco Bay area (South Bay would be great). There seems to be surprisingly little, easy to find information on the internet about this.

Comment: Voting to close as primarily opinion-based there is no criteria for users to vote on toward a "best" answer.

Comment: Is 'growler' a US term?

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite the South Bay but close. I've seen them fill growlers that do not have their name on them.

[Steelhead Brewing Company](http://steelheadbrewery.com/)

333 California Dr

Burlingame, CA 94010

United States

If you like IPAs or APAs, the Bombay Bomber and the Double Play are worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Most places (generally everywhere and certainly in Bay Area) allow only their own growlers to be filled with their beer. Thus if you buy a Growler from ISO Beers, they will not fill it at Original Gravity 2 blocks away (both very decent places).

It is just not good business - they want you to come in and pay premium on their single draft beers. So if you want to take some to go they want to at least win your loyalty by giving you discount on Growler fill, but make sure you come back to their brewery.

Comment: Well technically it is against California law for a brewery to fill growlers with other brewery's name/logo on it. There is a way around this though by covering it up (I have used tape). In San Diego, any place has happily filled or even supplied the tape. I will have to try those places you mentioned though, maybe I'll have some luck.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite place to fill up a growler is Hopdogma near Half Moon Bay.  It's worth the drive up from San Jose or down from San Francisco on a beautiful day.  You can see the ocean from the bar as well and it's a great place to have a pint!